# Using Android Emulators in a Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Here’s my scenario: I’m trying to set up a series of Windows virtual machines that people can remote into to develop Android apps.

Here’s the problem: As far as I know using x86 and hardware acceleration is not an option in virtual machines—at least not without jumping through ridiculous hoops—and without hardware acceleration all Android AVDs are ridiculously slow. Even on a very high-end Windows VM the AVDs consistently time out and are unresponsive.

So what are my options here? I could use a third-party service like Genymotion, but I would prefer to stick with the stock emulators if possible. Do I have any way to get this working?

Comment: I'm not even sure Genymotion would work. That requires VirtualBox. I.E. A VM in an VM

Comment: @cricket_007 Good point, I hadn’t even considered that.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Intel HAXM package will really speed up the Android emulators: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

It's a must-do if you are on Windows and using the google emulators.